How to Add a Legend to a Forest Taxonomy Diagram in LaTeX?
I have a LaTeX code that generates a taxonomy diagram using the forest package. I'm trying to add a legend to this diagram, explaining the meaning of the various colors, dashed lines, and node types. Specifically, I want to position the legend to the left of the diagram, without modifying the main structure of the forest tree itself.
Here is the current code:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        grow'=south, 
        draw, 
        rounded corners, 
        align=center, 
        l sep=15pt, 
        s sep=15pt,
        edge=dashed, thick % make edges to highlighted nodes thicker and dashed
    }
    [Skyline Query \\ over Data Stream
        [Type of Sliding Window
            [Count Based, text=blue, fill=green, edge={dashed, thick}]
            [Time Based, text=blue, fill=green, edge={dashed, thick}]
        ]
        [Processing Type
            [Distributed]
            [Centralized, text=blue, fill=green, edge={dashed, thick}
                [CPU with many cores, text=blue, fill=green]
            ]
            [Cloud]
        ]
        [Algorithm Approach
            [Sequential]
            [Parallel, text=blue, fill=green, edge={dashed, thick}]
        ]
        [Type of Data
            [Uncertain Data]
            [Certain Data, text=blue, fill=green, edge={dashed, thick}]
        ]
        [Type of Query
            [Single Query, text=blue, fill=green, edge={dashed, thick}]
            [Multi Query]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}

What I want:

Add a legend to explain:

Blue text: denotes our query.


The legend should be positioned to the left of the "Skyline Query over Data Stream" text, without interfering with the structure of the tree itself.


What I tried:
I have attempted adding tikz nodes next to the forest diagram, but encountered issues with positioning and grouping limits. I am hoping to get a solution that maintains the layout of the forest tree while adding a clear and concise legend.

welcome! your tree is already very wide. do you need to be able to fit more into the legend?

You can add nodes using regular tikz and position them relative to the tree. Either you can name the nodes or you can use 'nodewalk'-style names. Since we want to position relative to the root node, I used the latter as !r is straightforward enough. I used the positioning library to position the second node used to make up the legend.
I also removed the text=blue, fill=green and replaced it with a query style. Note that blue-on-green may not show up very clearly as blue. On my screen, it is more-or-less indistinguishable from black-on-green.
You do not need to specify the edge options for every node as you have specified them with for tree, so I also removed those.
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    grow'=south,
    draw,
    rounded corners,
    align=center,
    l sep'=15pt,
    s sep'=15pt,
    edge=dashed, thick % make edges to highlighted nodes thicker and dashed
  },
  /tikz/query/.style={text=blue,fill=green},
  [Skyline Query \\ over Data Stream
    [Type of Sliding Window
      [Count Based, query]
      [Time Based, query]
    ]
    [Processing Type
      [Distributed]
      [Centralized, query
        [CPU with many cores, query]
      ]
      [Cloud]
    ]
    [Algorithm Approach
      [Sequential]
      [Parallel, query]
    ]
    [Type of Data
      [Uncertain Data]
      [Certain Data, query]
    ]
    [Type of Query
      [Single Query, query]
      [Multi Query]
    ]
  ]
  \node [anchor=base west,query,draw,rounded corners] (legend-blue) at (!r.base -| current bounding box.west) {Text};
  \node [right=of legend-blue.base,anchor=base west] {denotes our query};
\end{forest}

\end{document}


